# R Shiny Layouts

Tags: r, plot, layout, shiny, fluid-layout

In my shiny dashboard, I am currently plotting 1 bar graph above, and 4 pie charts below, as follows:

```
fluidRow(
  column(12, plotOutput("bar1"))),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, plotOutput("pie")),
    column(3, plotOutput("pie2")),
    column(3, plotOutput("pie3")),
    column(3, plotOutput("pie4")))
```

How would I go about plotting the bar chart alongside the 4 pie charts, with the pie charts arranged in a square?

Effectively the bar chart would be `column(6,...` and all of the pie charts would be `column(3,...` but I would need the bar chart to extend to 2 rows so the pie charts are plotted directly beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `plotOutput` has a height of `400px`

> plotOutput(outputId, width = "100%", height = "400px", click = NULL,
>   dblclick = NULL, hover = NULL, hoverDelay = NULL,   hoverDelayType =
>   NULL, brush = NULL, clickId = NULL, hoverId = NULL,   inline = FALSE)

So you can do the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, plotOutput("bar1",height = "800px")),
    column(6,
           column(6, plotOutput("pie")),
           column(6, plotOutput("pie2")),
           column(6, plotOutput("pie3")),
           column(6, plotOutput("pie4"))

    ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$bar1 <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(1:100));box();grid()
  })
  output$pie <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(1:100));box();grid()
  })
  output$pie2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(1:100));box();grid()
  })
  output$pie3 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(1:100));box();grid()
  })
  output$pie4 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(1:100));box();grid()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]