# Display Table and Chart side by side in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to using R and R Shiny, but I'm trying to build a UI page that displays a table of data and a chart next to it. At the moment they are displaying underneath each other and I have tried taking suggestions from other peoples Q&As on here with little luck.

The code I have so far is:

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tab",
              tabPanel("Data by Year", dataTableOutput("Year_table")), htmlOutput("Year_Chart")),
              tabPanel("Data by Month", dataTableOutput("Month_table"))
              )
        )
```

I know I haven't provided the whole code but as this is where the layout for the main panel resides I was hoping someone with a little more expertise than me could help on this part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003279/r-shiny-layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using rows and columns like this

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tab",
              tabPanel("Data by Year", 
                       shiny::fluidRow(
                         column(
                           width = 6,
                           dataTableOutput("Year_table")
                         ),
                         column(
                           width = 6,
                           htmlOutput("Year_Chart")
                         )
                        )
              ),
              tabPanel("Data by Month", dataTableOutput("Month_table"))
              )
  )
```

Hope this helps